# Memory layout in multilevel inheritance and empty base optimization

Tags: c++, inheritance, sizeof, memory-layout

Consider the following inheritance:

```cpp
struct Empty {};

struct A: Empty {
    int64_t a;
    int8_t b;
};

struct B: A {
    int32_t c;
};
```

The sizeof of `B` is 16 on GCC and Clang, but 24 on MSVC. If you remove inheritance `A` from `Empty`:

```cpp
struct A {
    int64_t a;
    int8_t b;
};

struct B: A {
    int32_t c;
};
```

the sizeof of `B` suddenly becomes 24 on all 3 compilers. I guess that it is related to empty base optimization, but I can't figure out the actual layout (and the reasoning for such) of these classes in memory in different cases and compilers. Also, I would appreciate references to the standard that say something about EBO in multilevel inheritance.

I tried to look at `offsetof(B, c)` on GCC and Clang in different inheritance scenarios. In the first case, it's equal to 12 and 16 in the second, but I don't understand why.

Comment: `B` is not standard-layout. Therefore the standard doesn't specify basically anything about its layout (except ordering of some subobject addresses). The layout rules are determined by the applicable ABI specification, e.g. the [C++ Itanium ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) on GCC/Clang + Linux. MSVC uses its own ABI.

Comment: `A` is standard-layout, but the only thing that implies per standard is that the offset of `Empty` in the first example and `a` in the second example are zero (relative to `A`'s address).

Comment: It seems it is not about empty base optimization but about `A` being non-POD when inheriting `Empty` - you can reproduce the behavior without inheritance but e.g. declaring destructor: `struct A { ~A() {} .... };` The spec linked above says: `We ignore tail padding for PODs because an early version of the standard did not allow us to use it for anything else and because it sometimes permits faster copying of the type.` - I believe this is the answer: if the base type is non-POD they use its tail padding for inherited class data.

Comment: Does it actually matter? Will those few extra bytes be a problem for you?